# wrong color conversion with colorspace package

Tags: r, colors

Look at the following example:

```
> library(colorspace)
> # convert color with coordinates (0.2,0.3,0.4) in the RGB space into a character string:
> ( x <- hex(RGB(0.2,0.3,0.4)) )
[1] "#7C95AA"
> # reverse conversion:
> hex2RGB(x)  ## not the original coordinates !
             R         G         B
[1,] 0.4862745 0.5843137 0.6666667
> # now do the first conversion with the rgb() function from grDevices package:
> library(grDevices)
> ( y <- rgb(0.2,0.3,0.4) )
[1] "#334C66"
> # reverse conversion:
> hex2RGB(y)  ## close to the original coordinates
       R         G   B
[1,] 0.2 0.2980392 0.4
```

It seems that the conversion of three coordinates in the RGB color space into a character string is wrong with the hex() function from the colorspace package. Is it a bug, or is it me who wrongly use the package ?

Comment: try the gamma correction

Comment: Thanks. The command  hex2RGB(x, gamma=TRUE) yields coordinates close to the original ones.

Comment: StéphaneLaurent or @baptiste, post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The difference in the conversion is due using the linearized `RGB` color model instead of the gamma-corrected `sRGB` color model. The latter is employed by base R and most other software that generates colors for graphics. The former is relevant as an intermediate step to converting to other models such as CIE XYZ, also provided in the `colorspace` package as illustrated below.

[image: colorspace]

If you are using the `sRGB` function your example works as expected:

```
library("colorspace")
( x <- hex(sRGB(0.2, 0.3, 0.4)) )
## [1] "#334D66"
hex2RGB(x)
##        R         G   B
## [1,] 0.2 0.3019608 0.4
```

The reason for the difference on the G coordinate is that `0.3 * 255` is not an integer. (The hex color codes integers 0 to 255.)